Hide initially displayed box and table in modularized shiny app after clicking actionButton()
Here I want to hide an initially displayed box and datatable after clicking an actionButton in a modularized shiny app but only the box is displayed and then remains stable.
app.r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

# Load the modules
source("sideUI.R")
source("sideServer.R")
source("tabUI.R")
source("tabServer.R")

# Build UI & server and then run the app
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Text Hiding Example"),
  dashboardSidebar(sideUI("side")),  # Sidebar with the action button
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),  # Initialize shinyjs
    tabUI("tabPL")  # Table UI module
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Use the reactive in another module
  btn_input <- sideServer("side")
  tabServer("tabPL", btn = btn_input$btn)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

tabUI.R
tabUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    div(
      id = ns("showtab"),
      box(
        title = h3("Check our data", style = 'font-size:20px;color:white;
                     font-family: "Georgia", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;'), 
        status = "primary", 
        solidHeader = TRUE,
        width=12,
        height = 430,
        collapsible = TRUE,
        tagList(
          dataTableOutput(ns("table"),height = 400)))
    )
  )
}

tabServer.R
tabServer <- function(id, btn) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns  # Namespace function
      
      # Observe button click event
      observeEvent(btn(), {
        output$table<-renderDataTable({
          datatable(iris)
        })
        
        shinyjs::hide("showtab")  # Hide the text with correct namespace
      })
    }
  )
}

sideUI.R
sideUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("action"), "Hide Tab")
  )
}

sideServer.R
sideServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      return(btn = reactive(input$action))  # Return the button input as reactive
    }
  )
}


A few things:

You must wrap btn = reactive(input$action)) in list() in sideServer.R (otherwise btn_input is not a list containing an element named btn).  Alternatively, pass btn_input instead of btn_input$btn in app.R.  You need to do one or the other [this was the same issue in your previous question]

Use DT::renderDT() and DT::DTOutput(), instead of shiny::datatableOutput() and shiny::renderDataTable()

tabServer.R() should be re-written like this:


tabServer <- function(id, btn) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$table<-DT::renderDT({DT::datatable(iris)})
      # Observe button click event
      observeEvent(btn(), shinyjs::hide("showtab"))
    }
  )
}


tabUI.R should be adjusted:

tabUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    div(
      id = ns("showtab"),
      box(
        DT::DTOutput(ns("table")),
        title = h3("Check our data", style = 'font-size:20px;color:white;
                     font-family: "Georgia", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;'), 
        status = "primary", 
        solidHeader = TRUE,
        width=12,
        height = 430,
        collapsible = TRUE
      )
    )
  )
}

Here is a full version, all within single file:
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

sideUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("action"), "Hide Tab")
  )
}

sideServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      return(list(btn = reactive(input$action)))  # Return the button input as reactive
    }
  )
}

tabUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    div(
      id = ns("showtab"),
      box(
        DT::DTOutput(ns("table")),
        title = h3("Check our data", style = 'font-size:20px;color:white;
                     font-family: "Georgia", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;'), 
        status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, width=12, height = 430, collapsible = TRUE
      )
    )
  )
}

tabServer <- function(id, btn) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$table<-DT::renderDT({DT::datatable(iris)})
      # Observe button click event
      observeEvent(btn(), shinyjs::hide("showtab"))
    }
  )
}

# Build UI & server and then run the app
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Text Hiding Example"),
  dashboardSidebar(sideUI("side")),  # Sidebar with the action button
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),  # Initialize shinyjs
    tabUI("tabPL")  # Table UI module
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Use the reactive in another module
  btn_input <- sideServer("side")
  tabServer("tabPL", btn = btn_input$btn)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


actually this is how I go it       return(list(react = react, counted = counted, sci = reactive(input$sci),ver=reactive(input$ver), btn = reactive(input$action)))
but does not seem to work

tabServer("tabPL", btn = btn_input)
this does not work either

still does not work

that comment doesn't help me solve your probem, because you are not explaining what the problem is / what errors you are still getting.  I've added a full working version.
